# Is it possible to send a text message from my Mac programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sms, imessage

Since Apple has shut down their developer portal pending security upgrades they've created a status page so we can monitor what features they've brought back online. I've written a simple program to monitor this status page for changes.

My Mac is set up to receive iMessages sent to my iPhone. I'm wondering if anyone knows if its possible to have the program I've written send an iMessage to my iPhone when there's been a change in the status page Apple has up.

I usually develop for iPhone, so I appreciate any insight people can offer. The simple program I've written below checks every fifteen minutes if there's been an update and brings the update page up on Safari if there has been.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application


    NSDateFormatter *format = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:8*3600]];
    [format setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *text = @"";

    bool no_connection;
    do {
        text = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL]; // pulls the source html from Apple's update page
        NSString *status = @"No change";
        if ([text rangeOfString:[self currentStatus]].location == NSNotFound) { // if cannot find the old text, then there has been a change
            status = @"Update!";
        }
        no_connection = text == nil || [text length] == 0; // if no text or nil text then connection issue
        if (no_connection) {
            status = @"error making connection";
        }
        NSLog(@"status: %@",status); // report on status

        if (no_connection) { // if no connection then try again in a minute
            sleep(60);
            continue;
        }

        sleep(900); // wait 15 minutes (60 x 15 = 900) and check again

    } while ([text rangeOfString:[self currentStatus]].location != NSNotFound); // continue checking until there has been a change

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/"]; // bring up the update page in the browser
    if( ![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url] )
        NSLog(@"Failed to open url: %@",[url description]);
}

-(NSString*)currentStatus { /* returns the specific text in the html source that I'm checking for a change
                             "<span>" will be replaced with a hyperlink tag */
    return @"<span>Certificates, Identifiers &amp; Profiles";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do this once and never came up with an Objective-C solution.  However, you could have your app run AppleScript.  Here's how you'd do it from the command line:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send "Test Message" to buddy "MyBuddy"'
```

And the answer here describes how to run AppleScript from Objective C:

[Run AppleScript from Cocoa Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909702/run-applescript-from-cocoa-application)

Comment: the biggest disadvantage is: you can not send message to somebody with who you did NOT already started conversation.

Comment: It appears Apple removed this functionality from latest MacOS releases