# Mac: Programmatically un-minimize Application A from application B

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is this possible? or is this blocked from a security standpoint?

My goal is to un-minimize any 3rd party application that's currently minimized from my own application. Of course, this should work with any minimized window.

Comment: You cannot minimize an app. You can minimize a window. AppleScript does allow this normally.

Comment: Yes. of course I mean a window. So in theory, my application can create an AppleScript file, and then launch it to minimize a window of a 3rd party app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant Hide/Show an application, as uchuugaka noted, Applescript is probably the easiest and most straightforward way. Here's [an existing question with two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4909702/2167797), 1) for embedding an Applescript file into your application or 2) actually embedding the code into Cocoa/Objective-C.

I like the later myself (using [NSAppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsapplescript_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) since this is such a trivial thing to do.

```
NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Safari\" to set visible to true"];
[run executeAndReturnError:nil];
[run release];
```

Changing true to false will correspondingly hide the application.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use AppleScript for this:

```
for (NSRunningApplication* app in [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"])
    [app unhide];
```

If you want to activate it in addition to unhiding it, use `-activateWithOptions:` instead of `-unhide`.