# Open file in Finder window OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder, nsworkspace

My question is about opening a Finder window to show the file.

To open a single file, able to do by this :

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:file.path 
                 inFileViewerRootedAtPath:file.path];
```

Now I need to have a single Finder if user tries to open the same `file.path`.

To achieve this, I add `file.path` in an array.

But I am stuck when user closes the `Finder` window and again tries to open the file (as the active window has THE array with the path). Then Finder doesn't show :(

Any help how to proceed on this.

---

1. Is there a way to check the path for which the `Finder` window is open?
2. Is there a way to get a callback for the finder, so that I can remove the `file.path` from the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is done by simply passing `nil`.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:file.path inFileViewerRootedAtPath:nil];
```

Now same file / folder is selected even on multiple clicks.

Comment: Using Xcode 8.2.1 and compiling against OSX 10.11, the `nil` parameter needed to be replaced with `@""` to suppress the `Null passed to callee that requires a non-null argument` warning that appears.

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be creating finder like window in my application and open files in it, that would give you full control of your actions.

Second option could be creating scriptable cocoa app. That could provide functionality what you describe in your question also it is compatible with sandboxing. From Apple: [Gatekeeper and Signing Applets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_8/RN-10_8.html).

Summary from the link above.

> Gatekeeper and Signing Applets OS X Mountain Lion includes Gatekeeper,
>   which protects users from malicious software by applying a policy
>   about what downloaded software is allowed to run. Gatekeeper relies on
>   code signing to verify applications: a signed application is
>   guaranteed to have been created by the signer and to have not been
>   modified since it was signed. By default, Gatekeeper will allow
>   running only applications that have been signed by the Mac App Store
>   or an identified developer. If you write script applications
>   (“applets”) for distribution, then this policy applies to your
>   applets. To sign your applets so Gatekeeper’s default policy will not
>   block them:

What we need:

1. Create *.sdef file, which defines your application’s scriptability information. [Scriptability Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html)
2. Adding Cocoa scripting support to your app [Cocoa Support for Scriptable Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html)
3. Create Applescript to get open "named" Finder windows and send back information to your Cocoa app or vice versa.
4. Invoke Applescript from your app or vice versa.

You need to create *.sdef file, which is an XML-based format that describes a set of scriptability terms and the commands, classes, constants, and other information that describe the application's scriptability. You need to add this file into your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary title="YOUR_APP_NAME">
    <suite name="scriptTest Suite" code="MApN" description="YOUR_APP_NAME Scripts">
        <command name="myFirstCommand" code="lkpstrng" description="The array to lookup">
            <cocoa class="MyLookupCommand"/> 
            <direct-parameter description="The array to lookup">
                <type type="any" list="yes"/>
            </direct-parameter>
            <result description="returns and array" type="text"/>
        </command>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

After included the *.sdef file into your project you need to add two new keys to info.plist. Scriptable = YES and Scripting definition filename.

[image]

In scripting definition file `cocoa class` defined as `MyLookupCommand`, we need to create this class in Cocoa app. `MyLookupCommand` class it is subclass of `NSScriptCommand`

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyLookupCommand : NSScriptCommand
@end
```

.m

```
#import "MyLookupCommand.h"

@implementation MyLookupCommand

-(id)performDefaultImplementation {

    // get the arguments
    NSDictionary *args = [self evaluatedArguments];
    NSString *stringToSearch = @"";
    if(args.count)
    {
        stringToSearch = [args valueForKey:@""];
    }
    else
    {
        //  error
        [self setScriptErrorNumber:-50];
        [self setScriptErrorString:@"Parameter Error......."];
    }
    // Implement your code logic
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AppShouldLookupStringNotification" object:stringToSearch];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"result: %@", [NSDate date]];
}
@end
```

And this is how you capture communication from Applescript.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [textbox1 setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d", 1]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(getValueFromScript:)
     name:@"AppShouldLookupStringNotification"
     object:nil];
}

-(void)getValueFromScript:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [yourTextbox setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"from notification center %@", notification.object]];
}
```

Next step, we need a Applescript to get/set command from/to a Cocoa app.

```
//In SDEF file we declared return type as array, here we created one.
set groceryList to {"eggs", "milk", "bread"} //the variable which you want to send to your app.

//Scripting language is pretty straight forward. If "named" window exists invoke the command and send return type to your Cocoa app.
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    if ((count of windows) > 0) then
        if name of front window is "YOUR_DESIRED_FINDER_WINDOW_NAME" then

            tell application "System Events"
                set running_apps to every application process's name
                if running_apps does not contain "YOUR_COCOA_APP_NAME" then
                    tell application "AppleScript Editor" to activate
                end if
            end tell

            tell application "AppleScript Editor"
                if it is running then
                    tell application "AppleScript Editor"
                        myFirstCommand groceryList //Updated this line. 
                    end tell
                end if
            end tell

        end if
    end if
end tell
```

Of course you need to call Applescript applet from your Cocoa app as well. Please have a look at [How to call Applescript from cocoa App - regulus6633's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909702/run-applescript-from-cocoa-application)