# How to run an applescript through xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, applescript

Im trying to set up a MacOSX application through xcode to send an iMessage. I have an applescript that I have run through Automator to test to make sure it works. However, I want to be able to pass in parameters to the apple script so that it would look like this:

```
on run(thisContact, thisNumber, thisMessage)

    tell application "Messages"
        set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
        set targetBuddy to buddy phoneNumber of targetService
        repeat thisNumber times
            send thisMessage to thisContact
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

How would I run a script like this from xcode?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? How to build an Applescript App in Xcode? Or how to call an Applescript handler from Cocoa/ObjC? Or how to build an interface and connect it to your script? Please edit your question to be more clearer

Comment: @user1569940 Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909702/run-applescript-from-cocoa-application