# Redraw desktop background without restarting dock in OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am updating the wallpaper using the following function:

```
- (void)updateWallpaper: (NSString *)path {
    NSError * aerror;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:url forScreen:[NSScreen mainScreen] options:[NSDictionary dictionary] error:&aerror];
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary* desktopDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.desktop"]];
    NSMutableDictionary* bgDict = [desktopDict objectForKey:@"Background"];
    NSMutableDictionary* spaces = [bgDict objectForKey:@"spaces"];
    [spaces enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* key, NSMutableDictionary* obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [obj enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, NSMutableDictionary* prefs, BOOL *stop) {
            [prefs setObject:path forKey:@"ImageFilePath"];
            [prefs setObject:path forKey:@"NewImageFilePath"];
            [prefs setObject:@"Never" forKey:@"Change"];
        }];
    }];

    //NSLog(@"%@", desktopDict);

    [defaults setPersistentDomain:desktopDict forName:@"com.apple.desktop"];
    if ([defaults synchronize] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"synchronize failed");

    }

}
```

However, the update is not always rendered, in the sense that the old image continues to remain. I have tried various workarounds, the best I could come up with is writing the image to a new file (new file path) for every update. This works when I am working in the desktop space, but not if I am working in some other full-screen app space. The only thing which fixes this is to reload the dock (by `system ("/usr/bin/killall Dock");`). This somehow redraws the wallpaper in between. But this causes the un-minimizing of all the minimized windows for all applications, which is not okay for my use. Is there some other way to reinforce the update?

Comment: As a simple solution, you can use AppleScript: `tell application "Finder"
 to set desktop picture to "<file name>" as alias`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909702/run-applescript-from-cocoa-application) on how to include an AppleScript in your app. A more elaborate approach in this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2084/_index.html

Comment: This strikes me as the sort of thing where it is best to just file a bug on Apple and let them fix it; it's their bug.

Comment: @Monolo did that, does not help. Same scenario.

Comment: It seems that the alias file ref does not work for this in El Capitan. See my answer for a method that works for me.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I can't even get persistentDomainForName("com.apple.desktop") to return something non-nil.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I am running in the same exact problem now.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can consider using AppleScript. It may not be the most elegant solution, but integrating AppleScript into apps is a  documented technique, so it should be safe.

In OS X 10.11 you can change the wallpaper with a single line of script. Notice that you have to use a POSIX file, aliases do not seem to work.

To test it from the command line, try this in Terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "<full path to image file>"'
```

[This doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2084/_index.html) explains how to use AppleScript from an app.

Comment: This does not help. The same scenario remains, the wallpaper change is not rendered if I am working in a fullscreen application.